# Firestore model group/members to query or database rules

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm designing the classic groups/members for firebase firestore

What is the best design to query groups that I'm a member of? And lock via rules access to the group.

I'm trying to query:
IOS-Swift:

```
let query = groupRef.whereField("members.{member}.userUid", isEqualTo: self.userID!)
```

today I have something like this: (willing to change data model for a better solution)

```
groups:
   groupUid:
     groupName: A Name
     members: 
       0:
         userName: A user
         userUid: A uid
       1:
         userName: A user
         userUid: A uid
       2:
         userName: A user
         userUid: A uid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Firestore Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays) recommend a data model like this:

```
groups:
   groupUid:
     groupName: A Name
     members: 
       uid1:true
       uid2:true
       uid3:true
```

So that you can run the query:

```
let query = groupRef.whereField("members." + self.userID!, isEqualTo: true)
```

Comment: This solution will not scale if your group has thousands of members as your document will eventually exceed a document size limit.